# problem with theorem, tikzpicture and center environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, theorems

I use a dialog-bubble style for some theorems, by using the code below, that works fine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes} % Για φάνσι κουτακια

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theo}{Sometheorem}[chapter]

\tikzstyle{BoxDialog} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
rectangle callout, rounded corners, densely dashed,callout relative pointer={(-0.4cm,-0.4cm)}, inner sep=4pt, inner ysep=8pt]
\tikzstyle{TitlTheo} =[fill=white, text=black]

\NewEnviron{dialogtheo}[1]{
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [BoxDialog] (boxtheo){%
            \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
            \BODY
            \end{minipage}
        };
        \node[TitlTheo] at (boxtheo.north) {\textbf{#1}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{dialogtheo}{title theorem}
\begin{theo}
    theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem
\end{theo}
\end{dialogtheo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I wrap `center` environment around the `dialogtheo` environment like this:

```
\NewEnviron{dialogtheo}[1]{
        \begin{center}
                        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [BoxDialog] (boxtheo){%
            \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
            \BODY
            \end{minipage}
        };
        \node[TitlTheo] at (boxtheo.north) {\textbf{#1}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
}
```

I have this error report:

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a
>   missing \item.

[This](https://pastebin.com/kb0giKnu) is the `log`-file.

What is the problem?

P.S.: If I ceep `center` environment, but I delete `theo`, everything is OK again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to center the dialog bubble, instead of using the `center` environment, you should try to use `\centering` with a `\par` at the end of the content of your environment:

```
\NewEnviron{dialogtheo}[1]{
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[BoxDialog] (boxtheo){
            \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
                \BODY
            \end{minipage}
        };
        \node[TitlTheo] at (boxtheo.north) {\textbf{#1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\par
}
```

The `\par` is important, else the bubble will not be centered at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you try to place a theorem inside `center` environment, you will realize that it doesn't work.

**Edit: I mean that the code:**

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{theo}
    test
    \end{theo}
\end{center}
```

would result to a non-centered theorem.

So, my solution is a "hack" that just indenting your environment as much as needed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations} % Για φάνσι κουτακια

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theo}{Sometheorem}[chapter]

\tikzstyle{BoxDialog} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
rectangle callout, rounded corners, densely dashed,callout relative pointer={(-0.4cm,-0.4cm)}, inner sep=4pt, inner ysep=8pt]
\tikzstyle{TitlTheo} =[fill=white, text=black]

\newsavebox{\theobox}
\newlength{\theoidentlength}
\NewEnviron{dialogtheo}[1]{
\savebox\theobox{\hbox{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [BoxDialog] (boxtheo){%
            \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
            \BODY
            \end{minipage}
        };
        \node[TitlTheo] at (boxtheo.north) {\textbf{#1}};
        \end{tikzpicture}}}
        \setlength\theoidentlength{\dimexpr(\textwidth-\wd\theobox)/2\relax}
        \noindent\hspace*{\theoidentlength}\usebox{\theobox}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{dialogtheo}{title theorem}

\begin{theo}
    theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem
\end{theo}
\end{dialogtheo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: My solution is just an alternative [that I think could be useful in many cases if centering fails], and just added as such (an alternative) approach.

Comment: I don't agree with you about theorems problem with centering. If I wrap around `\BODY` the command  `\begin{center}Something\end{center}`, like this: `\begin{center}Something\end{center}\BODY\begin{center}Something\end{center}`, then there is no problem with centering the dialog and the theorem.

Comment: Γεια σου @ΚώσταςΚούδας (:Hi) : check the edit to see what I mean because possibly I didn't understood your goal or/and you didn't understood what I tried to do.

Comment: Καλημέρα, @koleygr ! I thought that you meant that if I put a theorem in a `center` environment, I 'll have errors. So I understand your proposition!

Comment: No, as you see, it will not give errors, but will just use all the available text width. Something like `\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{theo}
    test
    \end{theo}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}` would center anyway... My proposal is just a more general approach that could help in similar problems. (Just adding for its idea.) Have a nice day. PS: Replace the library `snakes` with `decorations` as your compiler is suggesting.